# Create a new column conditional to a list in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I am trying to create a new column conditional to my column Decision_list (which is a list). I would like to assign the colour red whenever Upwind is in the string, and blue when Upwind is missing.

```
df_sub <- structure(list(Index = c(14L, 788L, 789L, 792L, 793L), Decision_list = list(
    "NoDetection", c("NoDetection", "Upwind", "Upwind"), c("NoDetection", 
    "Upwind"), c("NoDetection", "Upwind", "Upwind"), c("NoDetection", 
    "Upwind", "Upwind"))), .Names = c("Index", "Decision_list"
), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

I tried:

```
df_sub$NewColumn <-
        ifelse(df_sub$Decision_list %in% c("Upwind"), "Red",      
"Blue")
```

or something looking like:

```
gh <- df_sub$Decision_list
for( i in seq_along(gh)){   
    ff <- gh[[i]]
  gh[[i]] <- ifelse(unlist(ff) %in% c("Upwind"), "Red",       
"Blue")
}
```

Both options failed to create the column I want. For example with option 1, I get blue 5 times while I should get it only for the first row. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `df_sub$NewColumn <- c("Blue", "Red")[grepl("Upwind", df_sub$Decision_list) + 1]`

Comment: why the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lists as columns in `data.frame`'s are not very handy, hence I would rather create a character column first.

```
# Transform column
df_sub$Decision_list <- sapply(df_sub$Decision_list, paste, collapse = ",") 

# Use ifelse with grepl to create new column
df_sub$NewColumn <- ifelse(grepl("Upwind", df_sub$Decision_list), "Red", "Blue")

>df_sub
#  Index             Decision_list NewColumn
#1    14               NoDetection      Blue
#2   788 NoDetection,Upwind,Upwind       Red
#3   789        NoDetection,Upwind       Red
#4   792 NoDetection,Upwind,Upwind       Red
#5   793 NoDetection,Upwind,Upwind       Red
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df_sub %>%
  rowwise()%>%
  mutate(NewColumn = ifelse("Upwind" %in% Decision_list, "Red", "Blue"))%>%
  ungroup()
```

You want to be testing whether `"Upwind"` is in `Decision_list`, not the other way around (`Decision_list` will never be in the string `"Upwind"`, unless the list only contains the string `"Upwind"`)